# gethibernatetemplate().save(object) does not persist data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have bellow code stuffs and I'm using spring and hibernate

//main method in main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String[] path = new String[]{"applicationContext.xml"};
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(path); 
        serviceObj = (ServiceClassType)context.getBean("serviceBean");
        serviceObj.doTask();  

    }
```

//service method in service class

```
doTask(){
Obj obj=new Obj();
obj.setValue1("value1");
obj.setValue2("value2");
myDao.saveObject(obj);

}
```

//in dao class
//scenario #1

```
saveObject(Obj obj){
gethibernatetemplate().save(obj);
}
```

//scenario #2

```
saveObject(Obj obj){
session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        tx.commit();
}
```

***scenario #1 does not persists data but scenario #2 working fine. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Scenario 1 is lacking proper transaction management, whereas scenario 2 has manual tx management.

Answer (score 0):

> Hibernate Session doesn't work  without Transaction in standart configuration. If you add this property`<property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>` scenario #1 will work .

Comment: If I add my scenario #1 to J2EE application. It is working. But, when i'm using with a main method like above it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because Hibernate doesn't commit the transaction by default. I would recommend to use [Spring's Transaction Manager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) to handle this logic, instead of manual commit/rollback. It automatically commits transaction if everything went fine, and rollbacks the transaction in case of any error. With correct Spring configuration your code will look like:

```
class ServiceClassType {
   @Transactional 
   public doTask(){
      // update entities with your DAO classes
   }
}
```

Comment: I added the @Transnational annotation in service layer too. But, It didn't work.

Comment: Have you configured TransactionManager instance in your Spring configuration?